# SQL Blind Query: Convert Unknown DateTime into VARCHAR

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, datetime

I'm working on a C# project that has a method in it that queries many tables and output them as Excel worksheets. Such tables' tablenames are stored in an array and thus the command text is built programmatically, i.e.,

```
string query = string.empty;

foreach (string tbl in tables) {

    query = $"SELECT * FROM {tbl} WHERE DATEFROM BETWEEN @from AND @to"; // DATEFROM field is guaranteed to exist

    // run the SQLCommand here
    // e.g. I fill a ds (as DataSet object) with the query result

}
```

There's no bug in this code however once I export the DataTable/Dataset to Excel using the ever-so-convenient

```
xmlMap = myWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(ds.GetXmlSchema(), "Export");
myWorkbook.XmlImportXml(ds.GetXml(), out xmlMap, true, xlWsht.Range["A1"]);
```

. . . I sometimes get an Excel Application-instance error saying that "Some information are exported as text". I don't mind that. However, my clients are getting pissed because that error dialog does not grab focus and leaves users unaware of its existence underneath the pile of windows opened on their desktop, not to mention it is waiting for user-response from user to click OK.

After few experimentation,

```
// CONVERT(varchar, A_DATE_FIELD, 120)
```

solves the issue (avoids this error message to pop-up any more). However, due to the number of tables and so many different datetime fields in each of them, It's impractical (at least in my situation) to hardcode all the SELECT CONVERT(varchar, A_DATE_FIELD, 120) queries.

What's your solution on this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by querying the INFORMATION SCHEMA

```
public static string GenerateSafeSelectAllQueryString(string tableName, SQLDateConversionStyle dateConvertType) {

        var retval = new StringBuilder();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(PSQLServerUtilities.ConnectionStringStatic)) {

            string query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=@tableName ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC;";

            try {

                con.Open();

                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con)) {

                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableName", tableName);

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {

                        if (reader.HasRows) {

                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName)) {

                                dt.Load(reader);

                                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
                                    retval.Append((row[1].ToString() == "datetime") ?
                                        $"CONVERT(varchar, {row[0].ToString()}, {(int)dateConvertType}) AS '{row[0].ToString()}', " : $"{row[0].ToString()}, ");
                                }

                                retval.Length -= 2;

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            } finally {
                con.Close();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

        }

        return retval.ToString();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Different types of converting SQL DateTime to varchar
    /// Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp
    /// </summary>
    public enum SQLDateConversionStyle {
        /// <summary>
        /// Format: mon dd yyyy hh:miAM/PM
        /// </summary>
        Default = 100,
        /// <summary>
        /// Format: mm/dd/yyyy
        /// </summary>
        US = 101,
        /// <summary>
        /// Format: hh:mm:ss
        /// </summary>
        HoursOnly = 108,
        /// <summary>
        /// Format: yyyy/mm/dd
        /// </summary>
        Japan = 111,
        /// <summary>
        /// Format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss
        /// </summary>
        ODBCCanonical = 120,
        /// <summary>
        /// Format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm
        /// </summary>
        ODBCCanonicalMillis,
        /// <summary>
        /// Format: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ
        /// </summary>
        ISO8601 = 127
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about querying all of the columns in the given table and building your query from that, instead of "SELECT *"?  Sorry, I am not very familiar with SQL Server, but in Oracle you can query dba_tab_cols to get all of the columns for a table and each column's datatype. While building the query string, if the column is DATE then build the conversion into your SELECT.